# kernel expression using numpy

Tags: numpy

I have a laplace kernel which is written as `k(x1,x2) = exp(-0.5||x1-x2||)`
I write it as

```
k = np.exp( - 0.5 * np.sqrt ( np.dot (x1,x1) + np.dot (x2,x2) - 2 * np.dot(x1,x2)))
```

Is this correct?
Also if I the kernel is `k(x1,x2) = exp(-0.5 ||x1-x2||^2)`, I write it as

```
k = np.exp (-0.5 * (np.dot(x1,x1) + np.dot(x2,x2)- 2 * np.dot(x1,x2)))
```

Is this correct?

Comment: What is the dimensionality of `x1` and `x2`?  If they're scalars or vectors that's fine.  If they're second-order tensors (matrices) you need a transpose in there.  If they're higher than that it gets complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly calculate the norm of an array by using :
numpy.linalg.norm(x)

```py
import numpy as np
k = np.exp(-0.5 * np.linalg.norm(x1-x2))
```